# styled-components animation back and forth based on props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations, styled-components

I want to have my main content slide in and back on specific prop

so I created the animation, and I thought I'll add reverse to it in the case the prop changes.

Now the below code works, but the only problem is on the first page load I can see the "slideOutContent" animation

I don't want it to happen, those slides happen only when sidebar is open and then it slides the content.

```
const slideInContent = keyframes`
  from {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 256px;
  }
`;
const slideOutContent = keyframes`
  from {
    margin-left: 256px;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
`;

// Here we create a component that will rotate everything we pass in over two seconds
const MainContentBox = styled.div`
  animation: ${props => props.slide ? `${slideInContent} forwards` : `${slideOutContent}`};
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
`;
```

and this is how I use this component:

```
class PageWithDrawer ... {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false
        };
    }

    toggleMenu() {
        this.setState(state => {
            return { open: !state.open };
        });
    }

    render() {
        ....other stuff

        <MainContentBox slide={this.state.open}>
              {this.props.children}
        </MainContentBox>

        ....other stuff
    }
```

Comment: I could do that, but it seems like a hack. I thought maybe I could find a better solution

Comment: If you store the variables above in the state, then you can check if the previous value is empty in `getDerivedStateFromProps`. I'm not sure though where you keep these variables - do you compute them in `render()` or somewhere else? Wherever that is, if it's ok to move them to `getDerivedStateFromProps`, then your can check if it's the first render or not without a 'hack'.

Comment: Thanks @Al.G. added some of the code. Would be happy if you have any other idea

Comment: @Al.G. just tested that scenario, and it seems it doesn't re-render the "MainContentBox" if the props I pass doesn't change. I'm not sure how "Styled-Components" is under the hood but probably the make sure not to re-render if no change to the props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're giving `MainContentBox` a boolean value but you have three conditions: a SLIDE_IN, a SLIDE_OUT and a NO_SLIDE condition.

To avoid an additional boolean flag for first render, you can make `state.open` what is called Enum in other languages - a holder for either of these three values.

```
// You can put these in a named {} for encapsulation
const NO_SLIDE = 0, SLIDE_OUT = 1, SLIDE_IN = 2;

class PageWithDrawer ... {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: NO_SLIDE, // Initial state
        };
    }

    toggleMenu() {
        this.setState(state => ({ open: state.open % 2 + 1 }));
    }
```

`state % 2 + 1` is the formula to convert 0 → 1, 1 → 2 and 2 → 1.

Now let's map our state variable to an animation property string:

```
const stateToAnimation = {
    NO_SLIDE: 'none',
    SLIDE_OUT: slideInContent + ' forwards',
    SLIDE_IN: slideOutContent,
}

const MainContentBox = styled.div`
  animation: ${props => ${stateToAnimation[props.slide]}};
`; // other props...
```

You might need to surround `props.slide` with `${}` too, I'm not sure about this syntax.

Comment: nice! much better then another flag

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use `transition` instead `animation`. In this particular example it should do the job, but I am not sure if it is always possible.